# How to calculate $\oint_{C}\frac{dz}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$ when $C$ is a circle around the origin with radius $1.5$?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

I wish to calculate $\oint_{C}\frac{dz}{z(z-1)(z-2)}$ when $C$ is
a circle around the origin with radius $1.5$.

I guess that I should somehow apply Cauchy's integral formula here,
but $\frac{1}{z},\frac{1}{z-1}$ are not analytical inside of $C$
so I can't define something like $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-2)}$ and calculate
$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-1)}$ by Cauchy's.

Can someone please help me understand how to calculate this integral
?

I am guessing there is some trick so I can use Cauchy's integral
formula, but I didn't manage to think of any such tricks.

Comment: Split your circle into two curves, each one surrounding just one singularity (or use the residue theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \oint_c \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)} dz = 2\pi i \; \left [ \; \text{Res}\left (f(z), 0\right ) + \text{Res}\left ( f(z), 1 \right ) \; \right ] = 2\pi i(1/2 - 1) = -\pi i  $$

Or simply, since pole of $z=2 > 1.5 $

$$ \oint_c \frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)} dz   = \oint_c \left(  \frac{1}{2 (-2+z)}-\frac{1}{-1+z}+\frac{1}{2 z}  \right ) dz \\ 
= \oint_c \frac{1}{2z}dz - \oint_c\frac{1}{z-1}  = \pi i - 2 \pi i = -\pi i$$

I hope I am not wrong!!

Comment: Thanks! How did you calculate the last two integrals (last line) ?

Comment: @Belgi check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Proof_sketch) and [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/part-i/lecture-5-integrating-complex-functions/)

Comment: Thanks, you are very kind! By the way: did you use the standard way of finding how to write it with partial fractions ? (or maybe you had a shortcut here ?)

Comment: @Belgi lol ... no, the standard way is to use Residue theorem, since i don't think we will be able to make use of partial fraction every time. I wrote it here since it was possible ... and it's easy to understand it.